# jQuery not found after using gem w/ coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a gem installed in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I included it in my application.js.coffee:

```
#= require jquery/jquery
```

But when I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get this error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery/jquery'
```

This is also happening to me with my CSS files (bootstrap gem).

This exact stuff worked for me on a different computer and I can't figure out what's changed. This is the repository I'm using if that helps.

Comment: it's just `#= require jquery`

Comment: @ussferox: do you know why it works for me as `jquery/jquery` elsewhere?

Comment: not sure - maybe you're running slightly different versions of gems or rails on the other computer? maybe gem files are stored differently and can therefore be accessed differently on different OSes/ruby version managers?